# Sonarqube - Getting Incorrect Technical Debt Measure in Plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube, technical-debt

I am developing a plugin in Java for SonarQube (version 4.3.2) and need to make use of `TECHNICAL_DEBT` metrics present in `CoreMetrics`. I wrote below code to get this metrics from my `Decorator`.

```
    Metric metric = metricFinder.findByKey(CoreMetrics.TECHNICAL_DEBT_KEY);
    data = context.getMeasure(metric);.getIntValue();
    LOGGER.debug("{}: {}", CoreMetrics.TECHNICAL_DEBT_KEY, data);
```

Everything works fine so far, But the output of this code is different from the Technical Debt displayed on the Sonar dashboard.

Output of this code: **`sqale_index: 15750`**

Dashboard displays: **Technical Debt 32d**

Am I missing something in my understanding or programming? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measure of the technical debt is stored in minutes in the DB. Which is consistent with what you see: 15750 (minutes) / 60 (minutes per hour) / 8 (working hours per day) = 32.8 days

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, for this info and the amazing SonarQube product. I was thinking of this metrics being in minutes but was confused with the workings in the documentation which says "Technical debt- sqale_index- Effort in days to fix all issues.". http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions#Metricdefinitions-Issues

Comment: Indeed, I updated the documentation, thanks for the notification.